# Grep wildcard in middle of string

Tags: grep, wildcard

Ok so the problem I am having is I have a file that contains numerous lines that look like this.

> {"cameraEndpoint":"your.url.here","cameraId":"20MP S Middle Port 2","warehouseId":"random"}

Thig is I only need is the actual cameraId I have tried some grep fu with no luck here is one of the commands I ran.

```
grep -o '\"cameraId\":\"*"' camlist.txt
```

But that only returns

> "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"
>   "cameraId":"

Where I actually need the data between the Quotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it properly, you want the attribute of `cameraId`, in your example being `20MP S Middle Port 2`.

If so, you can do this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=cameraId":")[^"]*' file
20MP S Middle Port 2
```

It fetchs all data from after `cameraId":"` till next `"`.

#### Test

```
$ cat file
{"cameraEndpoint":"your.url.here","cameraId":"20MP S Middle Port 2","warehouseId":"random"}
{"cameraEndpoint":"your.url.here","cameraId":"Hello S Middle Port 2","warehouseId":"random"}
{"cameraEndpoint":"your.url.here","camaId":"Hello S Middle Port 2","warehouseId":"random"}
$ grep -Po '(?<=cameraId":")[^"]*' file
20MP S Middle Port 2
Hello S Middle Port 2
```

Comment: +1 for classic solution. also to make your rep look nicer `9995` :D

Comment: Oh, thanks @Kent, in fact it is a trick I learnt from you :) With the next upvote I entered in the 10K club, uhms.